# Best pattern to build an API for conversion between any two types of tabular data (from/to XML, JSON, ADO.Net DataSet, CSV,Excel etc.)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, converters, tabular

I am working on C# code to deal with conversion between a variety of different data formats such as XML, CSV, JSON and possibly more formats in the future. For aforementioned data formats I already wrote the code to do the actual conversion.

Any possible combination should be possible in terms of conversion FROM => TO. Based on the above mentioned formats you would get the following set of possible conversions possibilities:

XML => CSV
XML => JSON
CSV => XML
CSV => JSON
JSON => CSV
JSON => XML

My question is how to best wrap my conversion code in an API which allows adding more conversions (i.e. ADO.Net DataSet => CSV and CSV => ADO.Net DataSet) in an extensible and maintainable way. Could someone give pointers to applicable pattern(s) and/or best practices would be applicable?  Or even better, some example skeleton code?